# Find command expression error

Tags: linux, bash, cron, find

I am having some difficulties with cron and bash,mostly bash.There's a script that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd somefolder/
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'somelog*.log' -mtime +7 –delete
```

and I added a cronjob for running this script:

```
40 9 * * * /script-location/script.sh
```

but it seems like I the job is not getting completed and not even running the command by hand is not being successful:

```
 find: paths must precede expression: –delete
 Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D    help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Any ideas why or any advices in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` in front of `delete` predicate is not generic dash (ASCII 45).

How did i find it:

Well, using `od`:

**Your one:**

```
$ od -c <<<"find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'somelog*.log' -mtime +7 –delete"
0000000   f   i   n   d       .       -   m   a   x   d   e   p   t   h
0000020       1       -   n   a   m   e       '   s   o   m   e   l   o
0000040   g   *   .   l   o   g   '       -   m   t   i   m   e       +
0000060   7     342 200 223   d   e   l   e   t   e  \n
```

**Correct one:**

```
$ od -c <<<"find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'somelog*.log' -mtime +7 -delete"
0000000   f   i   n   d       .       -   m   a   x   d   e   p   t   h
0000020       1       -   n   a   m   e       '   s   o   m   e   l   o
0000040   g   *   .   l   o   g   '       -   m   t   i   m   e       +
0000060   7       -   d   e   l   e   t   e  \n
0000072
```

Comment: thanks a lot.was really really useful.everyday on stackoverflow I learn a new thing...

Answer (score 1):

The `–` in your `–delete` is *not* a dash character.

Replace it and the command executes as expected:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'somelog*.log' -mtime +7 -delete
```

Comment: I am curious how that popped in

Comment: yeah.seems that way...never happenned before with sublime...oh.I know.... the email client does that